# Reordering Squarespace Index Image Blocks with CSS?

Tags: squarespace

I've seen this question a few times, but I haven't been able to re-purpose the code posted.

I'm trying to change the order of photo grids in Squarespace so it shows one way on desktop, but reorders on mobile.

I have index gallery pages that alternate image layouts (for full-bleed, I've got two images side by side, with text on one). I've altered the order on desktop so section1 = image on left, image with text on right, section2 = image with text on left, image on right (total of 4 sections).

On mobile view the flow is stacking the images, so I get image/image with text/image with text/image/image.

I there change the view order in each section?

webpage is: https://jaguar-dog-jzz6.squarespace.com/

Comment: You'll need to set your site's Visibility to "password" and provide that view-only password in order for others to view the site. See: https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/360002088548

Comment: Shoot sorry Brandon - I forgot it was set to private. Updated - PW is May2020

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following CSS, added via the [CSS Editor](https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/206545567-Using-the-CSS-Editor) will do what you need.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 640px) {
  #new-gallery-1 .Index-gallery-inner {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  #new-gallery-1 .Index-gallery-item:nth-child(2) {
    order: -1;
  }
  #new-gallery-2 .Index-gallery-inner {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  #new-gallery-2 .Index-gallery-item:nth-child(2) {
    order: -1;
  }
}
```

Or, if you prefer the LESS CSS, prefixed version:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 640px) {
  #new-gallery-1, #new-gallery-2 {
    .Index-gallery-inner {
      display: -webkit-box;
      display: -ms-flexbox;
      display: flex;
      -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
      -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: column;
      flex-direction: column;
    }
    .Index-gallery-item:nth-child(2) {
      -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 0;
      -ms-flex-order: -1;
      order: -1;
    }
  }
}
```

Use only one of the above snippets. What they do is use [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox) in order to adjust the displayed order of the elements at widths less than 640px.

Note that this is done by targeting the sections via `id`, which are set using the URL of the index page. So, if you change the URL of the index page in the back-end of Squarespace (to something other than `new-gallery-1` and `new-gallery-2`, you'll have to update the CSS. Similarly, if you add more sections, you'd want to add them to the CSS.

Comment: Hi Brandon - so I changed the index names and the change has reverted - I tried to updated the names in the CSS, but its not working. Can you tell me where I went wrong with updating the names? I appreciate your help :)

Comment: It's not the name from which the section gets its ID, but it is the URL Slug: https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/205814578-URL-slugs

Also, if it turns out a post solves your problem, don't forget to mark it accepted.

Comment: Thanks Brandon - I was using the URL slug (but it looks like I had added an extra # which threw it off). I've repeated the code for gallery 3 and 4, and it looks like it's working. Thank you again for your help!